# generated structure and memory links in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm generating data structure with function. And when I try fill it with few nested loops I have problem with memory link: result last loop set all previous.

If I use hand-writed structure which absolutely similar to function-generated it work good.

```
def data_fill(data, label):
    for item_index, item in enumerate(data):
        for subitem_index, subitem in enumerate(item['subitems']):
            value = 'item-%s-subitem-%s' % (item_index, subitem_index)
            data[item_index]['subitems'][subitem_index]['prop'] = value

    print('%s filled: ' % label, data)


def gen_data():
    subitems = []
    for subitem in range(2):
        subitems.append({
            'title': subitem,
            'prop': None,
        })

    data = []
    for item in range(3):
        data.append({
            'title': item,
            'subitems': subitems,
        })

    return data


DATA = [
    {
        'title': 0,
        'subitems': [
            {
                'title': 0,
                'prop': None
            },
            {
                'title': 1,
                'prop': None
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'title': 1,
        'subitems': [
            {
                'title': 0,
                'prop': None
            },
            {
                'title': 1,
                'prop': None
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'title': 2,
        'subitems': [
            {
                'title': 0,
                'prop': None
            },
            {
                'title': 1,
                'prop': None
            }
        ]
    }
]

DATA_GEN = gen_data()

data_fill(DATA, 'DATA')
data_fill(DATA_GEN, 'DATA_GEN')
```

Results:

DATA filled (**right**):

```
[
    {
        'title': 0,
        'subitems': [
            {
                'title': 0,
                'prop': 'item-0-subitem-0'
            },
            {
                'title': 1,
                'prop': 'item-0-subitem-1'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'title': 1,
        'subitems': [
            {
                'title': 0,
                'prop': 'item-1-subitem-0'
            },
            {
                'title': 1,
                'prop': 'item-1-subitem-1'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'title': 2,
        'subitems': [
            {
                'title': 0,
                'prop': 'item-2-subitem-0'
            },
            {
                'title': 1,
                'prop': 'item-2-subitem-1'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

DATA_GEN filled (**wrong**):

```
[
    {
        'title': 0,
        'subitems': [
            {
                'title': 0,
                'prop': 'item-2-subitem-0'
            },
            {
                'title': 1,
                'prop': 'item-2-subitem-1'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'title': 1,
        'subitems': [
            {
                'title': 0,
                'prop': 'item-2-subitem-0'
            },
            {
                'title': 1,
                'prop': 'item-2-subitem-1'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'title': 2,
        'subitems': [
            {
                'title': 0,
                'prop': 'item-2-subitem-0'
            },
            {
                'title': 1,
                'prop': 'item-2-subitem-1'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I think this happens because `prop` in `DATA_GEN` is link to one memory place. And I have some questions:

- How make my function-generated structure work right?
- Where read more about this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def gen_data():
    subitems = []
    for subitem in range(2):
        subitems.append({
            'title': subitem,
            'prop': None,
        })

    data = []
    for item in range(3):
        data.append({
            'title': item,
            'subitems': subitems,
        })

    return data
```

You are inserting the **same** `subitems` array into the data every time, so when you write one of its values:

```
data[item_index]['subitems'][subitem_index]['prop'] = value
```

You are updating that *same* `subitem`.

Solution - put the sub-item generation code inside the data generation loop, to create an *independent* `subitems` array for *each* data item:

```
def gen_data():
    data = []
    for item in range(3):
        subitems = []
        for subitem in range(2):
            subitems.append({
                'title': subitem,
                'prop': None,
            })
        data.append({
            'title': item,
            'subitems': subitems,
        })
    return data
```

The outputs now match as expected.

As a side note, since you are already iterating over the elements of the `subitems` arrays, the write statement can simply become:

```
subitem['prop'] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
def gen_data():
    subitems = []
    for subitem in range(2):
        subitems.append({
            'title': subitem,
            'prop': None,
        })
    data = []
    for item in range(3):
        data.append({
            'title': item,
            'subitems': subitems, # here
        })
    return data
```

Within this function, you only made one `subitems` list, and you're referring to it in multiple places. If you want different copies, create that list within the loop:

```
def gen_data():
    data = []
    for item in range(3):
        subitems = []
        for subitem in range(2):
            subitems.append({
                'title': subitem,
                'prop': None,
            })
        data.append({
            'title': item,
            'subitems': subitems, # here
        })
    return data
```